# Is there a way to detect if mb_substr should be used over substr?

Tags: php, wordpress, substr

I have two websites, one is in English one is a RTL language.
To create a custom excerpt in WordPress, I have created a function. But in the RTL site, if I use "substr()" to create the excerpt, I somtimes get this symbol replacing some letters:

�

And when I use "mb_substr()" the excerpt outputs correctly.

Is there a way to detect the context (the content that needs to be turned into excerpt) so it uses the correct function on the fly?

Comment: is there something that prevents you from using mb_substr() everywhere?

Comment: While I don't know either why you can't use only `mb_substr` I am guessing that the results of `substr` and `mb_substr` would be different for multibyte strings.